# Laravel Filter with multiple values

Tags: laravel, filter, eloquent

When trying to filter with only username or email code works fine.But when i am trying to filter with both email and username it returns empty.what i am missing

**User model**

```
public function scopeEmail($query, $email)
{
   $query->where('email','=', $email);

}
public function scopeUsername($query, $username)
{
    $query->where('username','=', $username);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function filter(Request $request)
    {

      $q = User::query();
      $email = $request->input('email');
      $username= $request->input('username');
      if (isset($email))
      {
         // simple where here or another scope, whatever you like
         $q->Email($request->input('email'));
      }

      if (isset($username))
      {
          $q->Username($request->input('username'));
      }
         //execute
       $results = $q->get();
       return response()->json(['issError'=>0, 'errorCode'=>0,'message'=>$results],200);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **When** to make filter easy:

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
   $q = User::query();
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $username= $request->input('username');

    $q->when($email,function ($query){
       $query->where('email',$email);
    });

    $q->when($username,function ($query){
       $query->where('username',$username);
    });

   $results = $q->get();
   return response()->json(['issError'=>0, 'errorCode'=>0,'message'=>$results],200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `where` in if statements

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{

  $q = User::query();
  $email = $request->input('email');
  $username= $request->input('username');
  if (isset($email))
  {
     // simple where here or another scope, whatever you like
     $q = $q->where('email', $request->input('email'));
  }

  if (isset($username))
  {
      $q = $q->where('username', $request->input('username'));
  }
     //execute
   $results = $q->get();
   return response()->json(['issError'=>0, 'errorCode'=>0,'message'=>$results],200);
}
```

Comment: Same result.. Returnig empty array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function filter(Request $request)
 {
   $q = User::query();
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $username= $request->input('username');
   if (!is_null($email))
   {
     $q = $q->where('email', $email);
   }

   if (!is_null($username))
   {
      $q = $q->where('username', $username));
   }

   $results = $q->get();
   return response()->json(['issError'=>0, 'errorCode'=>0,'message'=>$results],200);
}
```